How to prove the convergence of ACF in AR(2) model
Consider an AR(2) model:$$
y_t=\phi_0+\phi_1 y_{t-1}+\phi_2 y_{t-2}+e_t \text {, where } e_t \sim \text { i.i.d. }\left(0, \sigma^2\right)
$$
To ensure stationarity, we have:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\phi_2+\phi_1<1 \\
\phi_2-\phi_1<1 \\
-1<\phi_2<1
\end{array}\right.
$$
I'm trying to prove the model is short memory, that is to prove the ACF $\rho_j$ converges to zero when $j$ goes to infinity. In this case, $$
\begin{aligned}
\rho_1 & =\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma_0}=\frac{\phi_1}{1-\phi_2} \\
\rho_2 & =\phi_1 \rho_1+\phi_2=\frac{\phi_1^2}{1-\phi_2}+\phi_2 \\
\rho_j & =\phi_1 \rho_{j-1}+\phi_2 \rho_{j-2}, \quad \text { for } \quad j \geq 3
\end{aligned}
$$
I try to use Cauchy inequity:$$\rho_j^2 = (\phi_1 \rho_{j-1}+\phi_2 \rho_{j-2})^2 \leq (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)(\rho_{j-1}^2+\rho_{j-2}^2)$$
and then iteratively $\leq (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)^2(\rho_{j-2}^2+2\rho_{j-3}^2+\rho_{j-4}^2)$ and so one. In this way, I can construct $(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)^k$ which converges to zero quickly as $(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2) <1$ based on stationarity conditions. But I failed to prove the right part $\rho_{j-k}^2+C_k^1\rho_{j-k-1}^2+…+C_k^p\rho^2_{j-k-p}+…+\rho_{j-2k}^2$ is bounded.
Can anyone help me to prove the boundness or tell me another way to verify the short memory? And by the way, is there any general method for higher order of AR(p) models?

The Autocorrelation function (ACF)
$$\rho_j  =\phi_1 \rho_{j-1}+\phi_2 \rho_{j-2},$$
is a deterministic second-order difference equation, of essentially the same structure as the $AR(2)$, bar the constant term and the white noise.
Due to the conditions imposed for stochastic covariance-stationarity of $AR(2)$ on $(\phi_1, \,\phi_2)$ the ACF is not exploding.
Also it is not oscillating (because $|\phi_2|<1$). So it converges to a fixed point (maybe with damped oscillations, i.e. still converging but going above/below its fixed point as it approaches it).
Consider, therefore its fixed point,
$$\rho_j = \rho_{j-1} = \rho_{j-2} = \bar \rho.$$
The fixed point must satisfy the difference equation. So for $\bar \rho \neq 0$, we must have,
$$\bar \rho=\phi_1 \bar \rho+\phi_2 \bar\rho \implies 1 =\phi_1 + \phi_2. $$
But by the conditions for stationarity, this cannot happen. We conclude that the only value for $\rho$ that can satisfy the fixed-point equation is $\bar \rho = 0$, and so we conclude that the ACF converges to zero.
